# log partial exception stack trace in Ruby

Tags: ruby

To debug possible issues with some new method, I'd like to log the stack trace upon encountering a StandardError.

In my case the stack traces are extremely long and only the last few calls are of importance to me (to debug a possible issue, I need to know who was the caller).

Is there a way to log a truncated version of the stack trace association with the exception?

E.g.

`def some_unreliable_method
  begin
    # do unreliable things
  rescue => e
    log(
      error_message: e.message,
      backtrace: e.backtrace # the full stack trace is too long
    )
    # recover from exception
  end
end`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`e.backtrace` is just array and you can get only last N numbers of backtrace's lines:

```
# get last 10 lines    
e.backtrace[0, 10].join("\n\t")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of `log(error_message: e.message, backtrace: e.backtrace)`, just `logger.error(e)`
2. If that's still too long, take a look at `config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb`. It's well documented.